# CV2 Find Contours detecting the floor and not my target

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect the black tape on the floor, but whenever I try to increase the threshold to stop it from detecting the ground all it does is stop detecting the tape. [image]

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('tape4.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

#convert img to grey
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#set a thresh
thresh = 100
#get threshold image
ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create an empty image for contours
img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
# draw the contours on the empty image
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
#save image
cv2.imwrite('contours.png',img_contours)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use Use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` for finding pixels below `thresh` instead of pixels above thresh.

The reason you are detecting the floor, is that `cv2.threshold` marks (with `255` value), the pixels above `thresh`.
You want to mark the dark pixels below `thresh`.
You can compute: `thresh_img = 255 - thresh_img`, or use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` (result is the same).

I also recommend using [closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) morphological operation, for removing clutter.

Code for finding the tape:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('tape4.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

#convert img to grey
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#set a thresh
thresh = 20 # Set thresh to very low value (the tape is almost black).
#get threshold image
# Use cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV instead of cv2.THRESH_BINARY for finding pixels below thresh instead of pixels above thresh
ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Apply closing morphological operation
thresh_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (21,21)));

#find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create an empty image for contours
img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
# draw the contours on the empty image
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
#save image
cv2.imwrite('contours.png',img_contours)
```

Result:
[image]

For finding the tape, you can look for the largest contour within `contours`:

```
# Get contour with maximum area
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Result:
[image]